# Can't mount sparsebundle that used to be a Time Capsule backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, mount, time-capsule, sparsebundle

I used to have a Time Capsule with a backup of all my data contained on its internal hard drive.

That internal hard drive broke down and I couldn't access it anymore, so I disassembled the Time Capsule, removed the hard drive and sent it to a Data Recovery company.

I had to shell out $300 for the recovery. The company told me they could successfully recover the totality of the failed disk, and they made a clone of it on an external hard drive I gave to them.

I could mount this external drive and I am seeing three partitions, one of which contains a 380 GB sparsebundle with all of my data inside. The thing is that for some reason my system won't let me mount this sparsebundle.

When I double-click on the sparsebundle in Finder, I get the following error message: *"The disk image couldn't be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"*.

And when I attempt to mount it through the Terminal (by doing `hdiutil attach <path_to_the_sparsebundle>`), I get the following: *"hdiutil: attach failed - No such file or directory"*.

I tried looking up this error online but I got nothing useful.

It just doesn't make sense: how can there be "no such file or directory"? It's right there! I'M DOUBLE-CLICKING ON IT!

Please, if you know what I should do to mount this stupid sparsebundle, help me. I'm truly desperate and at a loss on how to proceed in order to recover my data.